# general compiling problem on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Tags: macos, ssh, compiler-errors

I am using a mac to ssh to various linux distributions. Whenever i try to compile some compilers to install some programs (climate models like WRF and MONARCH), I am getting different errors. On the other hand, if i try to ssh from an ubuntu which is installed on same mac (on VM), compilers have been compiling. And this happened many times. Even if i compiled  and cleaned from ubuntu to check if they are works or not, it doesn't work when i ssh from mac. I tried many times with different versions of compilers also. Problem isn't related with compilers, so, i think, must be about macOS.

Any ideas?

Thnx in advance

Comment: Your environment is likely different. Check the output of `env` in both cases.

Comment: @RobNapier no, everything is correct and working when i try via ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, and your environment when coming from ubuntu is probably different than when coming from mac. Have you checked that they are the same?  Does `ssh <remotehost> env` have the same values in both cases (and also `ssh <remotehost>` and then running `env`, which may be different than the other way)? If this is not the cause, you'll need to provide some hint about what the errors are.

Comment: This question is pretty vague in its current form. You should focus on a particular problem that you're having. [Edit] your question to show the exact commands that you're running and the results they produce on different systems.